# What does "!Z" and "!X" mean in a traceroute?

Tags: linux, firewall, networking

When you see "!Z" or "!X" in a traceroute, what does that mean?

Where is it coming from, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

!X means "communication administratively prohibited" and !Z "communication with destination host administratively prohibited" 
As far as I remember, you get !X on ipv4 and !Z on ipv6 and it should be documented in the man (8) pages.

Since Linux uses UDP for trace-routes, this can originate from a `--reject-with icmp-host-prohibited` rule at the destination. Some Linux distros have this as a default configuration. To fix this you need to reply with `--reject-with icmp-port-unreachable` on UDP ports 33434 through 33534.

Comment: Why those ports?

Comment: @KenSharp Because those are the ports traceroute uses. See the man page for a detailed description of the algorithm.